# Parameter inside a module inside a module

Tags: verilog

I have read about parameters and how to redefine them at module instantiation, but what if I have a parameter inside a module inside a module?  Say that I have a small module called `gen`:

```
module gen(input,output);
parameter n=2;
parameter m=10;
//do something
endmodule
```

That module is instantiated in another module called `top`:

```
module top(inputs,output);
gen gen1(inputs,output);
//do something
endmodule;
```

I am trying to make a testbench on the big module where I need to redefine the two parameters **n** and **m**:

```
module tb;
reg input;
wire output;
top top1(input,output);
endmodule
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One solution is to redefine the parameters at each level:

```
module gen(input,output);
parameter n=2;
parameter m=10;
//do something
endmodule


module top(inputs,output);
parameter n=2;
parameter m=10;
gen #(.n(n), .m(m)) gen1(inputs,output);
//do something
endmodule

module tb;
reg input;
wire output;
top #(.n(n), .m(m)) top1(input,output);
endmodule
```

Another solution is to keep your current module definition and use `defparam` in your testbench to hierarchically override the value of parameters:

```
module tb;
reg input;
wire output;
defparam top1.gen1.m = 4;
defparam top1.gen1.n = 5;
top top1(input,output);
endmodule
```